# Why is bash using single and double quotes literally?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a situation in Bash I've never encountered before and don't know how to resolve. I installed bash on Alpine Linux (Docker Container) and for some reason environment variables with quotes translate literally.

`MY_PATH="/home/my/path"`

`> cd $MY_PATH`

**Result**

`bash: cd: "/home/my/path": No such file or directory`

---

`> echo $MY_PATH`

**Result**

`"/home/my/path"`

---

Now if you try it without quotes it works

`MY_PATH=/home/my/path`

`> cd $MY_PATH`

**Result**

`bash-4.4#` (path changed)

---

`> echo $MY_PATH`

**Result**

`/home/my/path`

---

I've never seen this before as I expect bash to gobble up the outer quotes, not even sure what to search for in trying to resolve this.

To fully qualify the scenario let me point out that:

1. Using Docker with an Alpine (3.8) image
2. Installing Bash 4 on Alpine that usually defaults to ash shell

---

**Update**

This is starting to look like a docker issue. I'm using the [env_file in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) to push environment variables to a container and it looks like its literally copying quotes `" => \"`.

Thanks to @bishop's comment to try `od -x`

*container.env*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MY_PATH="/home/my/path"
```

Then inside the Alpine 3.8 container running `env`

`MY_PATH="/home/my/path"`

Update 2

Looks like there was a [bug around this that was closed.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3702) But apparently doesn't seem fixed. Is it because I'm the only one in the universe still using Docker Toolbox?

Comment: Are you sure you used `"` as the double quotes, not `“` or `”`?

Comment: Yep, very sure. It's the same problem with single quotes.

Comment: `echo $MY_PATH | od -x` and post the results.

Comment: OK, `’` and `‘` exist besides `'`.

Comment: `bash-4.4# echo $MY_PATH | od -x`
`0000000 2f22 6f68 656d 6d2f 2f79 6170 6874 0a22
0000020`

Comment: So when you're saying `MY_PATH="/home/my/path"`, you're not actually typing `MY_PATH="/home/my/path"` at the shell prompt?

Comment: @melpomene see my updated comments. Looks like Docker may be causing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

> These syntax rules apply to the `.env` file:
>
> - Compose expects each line in an `env` file to be in `VAR=VAL` format.
> - Lines beginning with `#` are processed as comments and ignored.
> - Blank lines are ignored.
> - There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that **they are part of the VAL**.

In particular, the env file is not a shell script and not seen by bash (your `#!/usr/bin/env bash` line is treated as a comment and ignored).

Comment: Thanks I was just reading through that, looks like the real issue here is that literal translation of quotes is not (my) expected behavior. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3702